# About changing linux scheduler / task struct

Tags: linux, kernel, scheduler

I am doing a uni assignment about modifying the linux scheduler.

The general idea is adding an integer on the struct of each task, that would be initialized as zero.

When the scheduler is called for any of those tasks, if that integer is zero, the normal linux scheduler applies. If it is one, then the scheduler wouldn't choose another task, instead giving the control back to that task.

So the problems i have are:

1. Need to add an integer on task_struct
2. Need to create a terminal command that can change the value of said integer
3. Need to make that modification on linux scheduler

And i am completely lost on how to do that, can't even find the task_struct definition on kernel code. Any tips, answers or guides would be appreciated :)

Tried to download all the kernel code (version 6.0.8) from kernel.org. Searched for useful resources and didn't find them.

Comment: "can't even find the task_struct definition on kernel code" - You could use some IDE for navigate the Linux kernel code. Or use some online for navigate code. E.g. the first reference in [that search](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.0.8/C/ident/task_struct) contains the definition of the struct.

Answer (score 0):

Some answer to your question

1. task_struct locates in this file /include/linux/sched.h.
2. One of the solution create some program in user-space which is going to call some function inside your Kernel Module
3. Probably you need change variable value when context execution change from TASK_PLANNING to TASK_RUNNING. This could be done in /kernel/sched/core.c. Just find in code.

Note:

- Don't forget init your value in function *copy_process (kernel/fork.c).
- If you need get value inside module. Please, use asm/current.h lib and var current. It's instance of task_struct.